# How to List Archive File Contents in GZ on google cloud without extracting and downloading

Tags: gzip, gcloud, unzip

Can I check the content of a gz file on google cloud storage without downloading and extracting? Thanks.

It seems “gsutil ls”only list the objects on cloud. I need know what files were archived in a gz file in google cloud storage.

Comment: What is an example of a name of one of these "gz" files? If it's something like `file.gz`, then there is one file in it, which is `file`. If it's something like `foo.tar.gz`, then the tar part is an _archive_ of files, listed using `tar tvf foo.tar.gz`.

Comment: It is a “foo.tar.gz” on google cloud bucket. The tar tvf command you mentioned is for a local archived file, right? However, I don’t want to download the fire from google cloud bucket. I am wondering  if there is a google cloud command  to list the content of the foo.tar.gz without downloading.